# Regex to accept only numeric input with whole and half decimal point

Tags: regex, wpf, textbox

I have used the below regex but it accept all values after decimal point. I want only whole numbers ( eg: 12) and half decimal point (eg 12.5)

Regex regex = new Regex("[^0-9.]+");
I want the below behavior.

For example

1. Valid numbers : 12, 12.5
2. Invalid numbers 12.1, 12.8

Comment: What about `12.53` (to match `12.5`)? You may wish to include it in your examples.

Answer (score 1):

Try using this pattern:

```
\d+(?:\.5)?
```

This would match whole numbers, as well as numbers which half just a decimal component of `0.5`.  If you also want to allow for `0.0` decimal endings, then use:

```
\d+(?:\.[05])?
```

For your actual code, you may use:

```
Regex regex = new Regex("@\d+(?:\.5)?");
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you share the full Regex format since it throws error.

Comment: I have used like this   " Regex regex = new Regex("\d+(?:\.5)?"); "  error getting as unrecognized escape sequence.  I have also  tried by including @ like this  Regex regex = new Regex(@"\d+(?:\.5)?"); but it accepts only character.